# android - Bitmap.createScaledBitmap results in a Bitmap sized -1

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, scaling

i try creating a scaled bitmap using that method but once i access the bitmap, my app crashes with the following message:

`"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()"`

When I debug it, I can see that immediately after calling "createScaledBitmap", the resulting bitmap has a size of -1, -1. if i use "createBitmap" instead, the resulting bitmap does show the size of the original bitmap.

Should nobody here know what the cause of this is... is there maybe a workaround to resize a bitmap differently? I couldn't find anything in the bitmap class but maybe somebody here knows another way?

Comment: what is dstWidth and dstHeight when you call createScaledBitmap?

Answer (score 0):

First, i want to clarify that you are getting an error from Bitmap.createBitmap method, not from Bitmap.createScaledBitmap. Syntax of createBitmap is as shown below,

> Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)

```
    Parameters
    source: The bitmap we are subsetting
    x: The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
    y: The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
    width: The number of pixels in each row
    height: The number of rows
    m: Optional matrix to be applied to the pixels
    filter: true if the source should be filtered. Only applies if the matrix contains more than just translation.
```

**An error is occured because,**

x, y, width, height values are outside of the dimensions of the source bitmap.